# How to uncouple and reduce/solve a system of 2nd order PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, cylindrical-coordinates, coupling

I have the following system of 2nd order PDEs in cylindrical coordinates,

$\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}  \left( \frac{h}{3} a - \frac{\ell^2}{2} \nabla^2 a \right) + \frac{\partial }{\partial r} \left(  \frac{h}{3} b - \frac{\ell^2}{2} \nabla^2 b \right)=0$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \left[ \frac{1}{\mu} \left(\frac{h}{3} b - \frac{\ell^2}{2} \nabla^2 b \right) + b \right] - \frac{\partial}{\partial r}  \left[ r \left(\frac{1}{\mu} \left( \frac{h}{3} a - \frac{\ell^2}{2} \nabla^2 a \right) + a \right) \right] = 0$

where h, $\mu$ and $\ell^2$ are constants, and $a$ and $b$ are the unknowns. These have a solution of the type,
$a=r^{3/2} g_a (\theta)$
$b=r^{3/2} g_b (\theta)$

And I would like to uncouple the system to reduce it and solve it to obtain $g_a (\theta)$ and $g_b (\theta)$. Following the suggestions by @Yuriy S I reach a system like,
$\frac{h}{3} r^{1/2} g_a' (\theta) - \frac{\ell^2}{2} r^{-3/2} \left(\frac{3}{4} g_a' (\theta) + g_a'''(\theta) \right) +\frac{h}{2} r^{1/2} g_b (\theta) + \frac{\ell^2}{4}r^{-3/2} \left(\frac{3}{4} g_b (\theta) + g_b'' (\theta) \right)=0$

$ \frac{1}{\mu} \left(\frac{h}{3} r^{3/2} g_b' (\theta) - \frac{\ell^2}{2} r^{-1/2} \left(\frac{3}{4} g_b' (\theta) + g_b''' (\theta) \right) \right) + r^{3/2} g_b' (\theta) - \frac{5}{2} r^{3/2} g_a (\theta) \left( 1 + \frac{h}{3 \mu} \right) - \frac{\ell^2}{4 \mu} r^{-1/2} \left( \frac{3}{4} g_a (\theta) + g_a'' (\theta) \right)   = 0$

But I'm unable to reduce/solve it.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

Assuming:

$$\nabla^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}$$

You have a system of **3rd** order PDEs (because there are operators of the type $\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \nabla^2$ and  $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \nabla^2$).

You need to take the suggested forms for $a,b$:

$$a=r^{3/2} g_a (\theta) \qquad b=r^{3/2} g_b (\theta)$$

And substitute them in the system of equations. You will obtain a system of ordinary differential equations for $g_a,g_b$ in $\theta$.

This is a tedious process, but simple, so I leave it to you.

If the ansatz is correct, everything with $r$ should disappear from the equations (otherwise $g_a,g_b$ would depend on $r$ as well which is contrary to their definition).

You will obtain a system of 3rd order ODEs which in some cases can be decoupled (possibly with increasing the order of equations) or it can't be, in which case it should be solved numerically with usual methods.

Comment: @ITdenmark, are you absolutely sure this operator has the form you suggest? Because usually this symbol means Laplace operator, which has the form I wrote above, in cylindrical coordinates

Comment: @ITdenmark, you are mistaken. Please reference a textbook or Wikipedia for Laplace equation in cylindrical coordinates https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator (see here section "polar coordinates")

Comment: @ITdenmark, I am bad with tensors, so I can't help you here. You might want to ask another question with your original problem statement, if it turns out to be inconsistent with the equations you posted here

Comment: @ITdenmark, I think new question would be better, however, why do you need to decouple it? If the system has no analytical solution, then solving it numerically as a system would be preferable